# Webbrowser object POST issues in Windows 8

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, windows-8, windows-7, ms-word

I am trying to use the Webbrowser.navigate function in Word 2013 with a VBA macro

The code I am having an issue with is:

```
Webbrowser.Navigate URL, , , myPostData, "Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" + Boundary + vbCrLf
```

This exact piece of code works fine in Windows 7, but in Windows 8.1 the IE window closes instantly and cannot process the post request.

Is there something that has changed in Windows 8? I have tried on multiple machines running 7 and 8.1, only 8.1 has this issue.

edit: here is the function in full, the URL I am using is an intranet url, so I cannot provide it

```
Sub IEPost(URL As String, FormData As String, Boundary As String)

  Dim WebBrowser: Set WebBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

  WebBrowser.Visible = True
   MsgBox (FormData)
  'Send the form data To URL As POST request
  Dim bFormData() As Byte
  ReDim bFormData(Len(FormData) - 1)
  bFormData = StrConv(FormData, vbFromUnicode)

WebBrowser.Navigate URL, , , bFormData, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" + Boundary + vbCrLf

  Do While WebBrowser.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: *Is there something that has changed in Windows 8?* Yeah, well, they took Windows and turned it into a tablet OS without a start menu. I'd think the version of IE is much more relevant than the OS version here. Can you include some of the surrounding code, like, enough to reproduce the problem? See [mcve].

Comment: Hi Mat, I added some additional code, hopefully that can give you more of an idea of what is going on

Comment: Are both Win7 and Win8 clients using the same version of IE?

Comment: Yes, same version of IE, 11.0.9.

Comment: Interesting. FWIW I've retracted my vote-to-close. Good luck!

Comment: At what point in the code does the IE window "close instantly"? Is it logging anything via Windows Error Reporting?

Comment: It was closing on the line for Webbrowser.navigate, I was getting error 440. I fixed it by using InternetExplorerMedium (its a secure connection, so I think that Webbrowser kept dropping it)